# postfix rewrite destination of mails from specific server group

Tags: postfix, rewrite

Hi I have smtp server on a local network and all other local machines send emails through this one (mastersmtp.lo.cal 10.10.10.10).

I need to rewrite all TO/destination address from test1.lo.cal (10.10.10.12) and abrakadabra.lo.cal (10.10.10.222) servers, which relay to my mastersmtp.lo.cal.

I think this should be done on mastersmtp.lo.cal. it uses postfix as mail software.

Maybe someone knows any most "default"/simple way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html

added to main.cf:

```
# for redirection some emails
  header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

content of: /etc/postfix/header_checks

```
/^From: (.*@test1.lo.cal)/ REDIRECT newDestination@awesome.com
/^Received: (.*10.10.10.12)/ REDIRECT newDestination@awesome.com
/^From: (.*@abrakadabra.lo.cal)/ REDIRECT newDestination@awesome.com
/^Received: (.*10.10.10.222)/ REDIRECT newDestination@awesome.com
```

reload restart and so on :) as always :)

```
postmap -q - pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks < /etc/postfix/header_check
systemctl reload postfix
```